# SWT Text: Remove default context menu item in Linux

Tags: java, swt

The default context menu for `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text` in Linux contains the "Insert Emoji" option.

Is there a way to remove that "Insert Emoji" option without removing other options?

[image]

Comment: SWT doesn't provide any way to change default menus.

Answer (score 1):

The default menu provided for the Text widget cannot be modified. But SWT provides a way to replace the default menu with your custom pop-up menu using `Text.setMenu()`.
Your code needs to implement the actions for all the menu items of the custom menu and also manage the clipboard.

For an example, please see: https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet122.java